# How can I encode a 32bit integer into a byte array?

Tags: python, arrays, string

I'm required to send a 32bit integer over a serial connection like so: `0xc6bf6f34` should become: `b'\xc6\xbf\x6f\x34'`.

To that end, I created this, but, as always after such coding, I wondered if it's *pythonicism* could be improved with something in the standard libary:

```
def ltonlba(value):
    ''' ltonlba : Long to Network Long Byte Array '''
    from socket import htonl
    value = htonl(value)
    ba = b''
    for i in range(4):
            ba += chr((value) & 0xff)
            value >>= 8
    return ba
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.2+, you can use [`int.to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes):

```
>>> 0xc6bf6f34.to_bytes(4, 'little')  # 4 bytes = 32 bits
b'4o\xbf\xc6'
>>> 0xc6bf6f34.to_bytes(4, 'little') == b'\x34\x6f\xbf\xc6'
True
```

Otherwise, you can use [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack) with `<I` format (`<`: little-endian, `I`: 4-bytes unsigned integer , see [Format strings - `struct` module doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-strings)):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('<I', 0xc6bf6f34)
b'4o\xbf\xc6'
```

---

**UPDATE / NOTE**: If you want to get big-endian (or network-endian), you should specify `'big'` with `int.to_bytes`:

```
0xc6bf6f34.to_bytes(4, 'big')  # == b'\xc6\xbf\x6f\x34'
```

and `>` or `!` with `struct.pack`:

```
struct.pack('>I', 0xc6bf6f34)  # == b'\xc6\xbf\x6f\x34'  big-endian
struct.pack('!I', 0xc6bf6f34)  # == b'\xc6\xbf\x6f\x34'  network (= big-endian)
```

Comment: Does the `struct.pack()` solution work with Python 3.2+ as well?

Comment: @Jamie, It works with both in Python 2.x, 3.x. I tested it in Python 2.7.13 / 3.5.3 / 3.6.1.

Comment: @Jamie, I rolled back your change. You want little little-endian according to your question.

Comment: @Jamie, If you specify network-endian (or big-endian) , you will get b`\xc6\xbf\x6f\x34` instead.

Comment: @Jamie, I updated the answer to explicitly mention it.